# Cron task does not get executed

Tags: command-line, server, cron

I have a list of commands to run every day. When I copy paste it directly to terminal and run it is working but when I copy paste the same command to cron its not working.

This is the command

`0 10 * * * commcare-export --query /home/administrator/Documents/commCareExcelFiles/case_data/1.xlsx --project projectX --output-format sql --output postgresql://user:pass12345@localhost:5432/dbname --username username@gmail.com --auth-mode apikey --password 0ecc3417ad8424ce5eac698092`

I can see in cron logs the following

`(administrator) CMD ( commcare-export --query/home/administrator/Documents/commCareExcelFiles/case_data/1.xlsx --project projectX --output-format sql --output postgresql://user:pass12345@localhost:5432/dbname --username username@gmail.com --auth-mode apikey --password 0ecc3417ad8424ce5eac698092)`

But when I check the database there are no new records, unless it's ran directly from terminal. L

Comment: You will need to specify the full path for `commcare-export`, as the cron job will not know where to look for that tool.

Comment: @matigo added absolute path too but still no result

Comment: You should migrate to systemd.timer.

Answer (score 0):

Twofold answer:

a) Check your local mailbox. If a cronjob encounters an error (more precisely: if it produces any output at all on stdout or stderr) it sends it via mail to the local `root` account which should be forwarded to your personal mail account. (If it isn't then you should fix that.)

b) Enter the absolute path for the command `commcare-export` in your `crontab` entry. `cron` does not inherit your `PATH` setting. It only looks for command binaries in the standard locations `/bin` and `/usr/bin`.  The command `commcare-export` is not a standard Ubuntu command. It is not unlikely that its binary resides in some software specific folder. To find out its absolute path if you don't know it, enter the command `which commcare-export` in a terminal where the command `commcare-export` is working.

Comment: I got the absolute path. It says `/usr/local/bin/commcare-export` I update my cron task but still no result

Comment: So what does the mail say?

Comment: i was trying to schedule a cron task for python package. Adding the path for python and after that commcare-export did the trick.